# IF Statement for Calculated Column where answer show negative number as #NUM!

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am creating a calculated formula to tell me Days Past Due and am trying to find a way to change the #NUM! to "ON TARGET".

## For Example:

**Item: A**

```
Start Date: 8/1/2018
    
Due Date: 8/16/2018
    
Days Past Due: #NUM!
```

**Item: B**

```
Start Date:5/27/2018
    
Due Date: 7/31/2018
    
Days Past Due: 6
```

**Code:**

```
    IF([Closure Date]="",(DATEDIF([Due Date],TODAY(),"d")),(DATEDIF([Due Date],[Closure Date],"d")))
```

Where in my IF Statement can I add the "ON TARGET" to replace the #NUM! or do I need to do another IF Statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can replace the `#NUM!` or `#Name!` error using `ISERROR()` function

So in your case, try to use the below formula

```
=if(ISERROR(IF([Closure Date]="",(DATEDIF([Start Date],TODAY(),"d")),(DATEDIF([Start Date],[Closure Date],"d")))),"On Target",IF([Closure Date]="",(DATEDIF([Start Date],TODAY(),"d")),(DATEDIF([Start Date],[Closure Date],"d"))))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @B.Ault glad to hear it helped you :)